# Can I delete songs of iTunes over my app?

Tags: mpmediaquery

I use MPMediaQuery class to query iTunes's songs, and then display them in my APP. But now, I received a new needs, that's delete songs. I find the MediaPlayer framework, there is no way to delete songs.

How could I do?

Thank you

Comment: Is unable to delete it?

Comment: I handled this way: I can APP was deleted and the deleted songs stored locally. The next time you enter the APP, load all the songs and determine which has been deleted, deleted songs does not display in the APP. The equivalent of false deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot. As the name suggests, the Media Player framework can only browse, select, and play media — it cannot modify the user's media collection, or the objects it contains.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, are there any other API can do it?